# debug angular resource promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I debug an angular ressource ?

If I do

```
var thing = service.getRessource();
debbuger;
```

When I'm at the breakpoint, the promise won't be resolved.

I would have to do

```
service.getRessource()
.$promise
.then(function(thing) {
    debugger; 
    // I can accesS the data here
});
```

Is there a way to debug the resolved promise without rewriting my code like in the second example ?

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda the whole point of promises, but..

For debugging porposes only. `$q` has a [$$state](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/q.js#L423) object as part of the promise that if the promise is instant, should have the data you require.
You can access it potentially by

`thing.$promise.$$state.value`

if you keep with the first example.

**Note**: this may not always be avalible because it not ansyncronous, if you are using the data in your actual code you should keep with the second method.